# Does the key of a HashMap have to be a pointer in Rust?

Tags: pointers, rust, hashmap, borrow-checker

I'm admittedly new to Rust. That being said, this doesn't make sense to me yet finding out why the behavior I'm seeing isn't what I expect seems like a good learning opportunity:

```rust
use std::iter::Enumerate;
use std::collections::HashMap;
impl Solution {
    pub fn two_sum(nums: Vec<i32>, target: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
        let mut numToI: HashMap<i32, usize> = HashMap::new();
        for (i,v) in nums.iter().enumerate() {
            let num: i32 = *v;
            let complement: i32 = target - num;
            if numToI.contains_key(complement) {
                return vec![i as i32, numToI.get(complement) as i32];
            } else {
                numToI.insert(complement, i);
            }
        }
        return vec![-1,-1];
    }
}
```

Here I'm doing [the simple question twoSum](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum). I understand that `nums.iter().enumerate()` will return the values `i` and `v`, which are of type `usize` and a *pointer* to the element in `nums` (so in this case a reference to an `i32`), respectively. The thing I'm having trouble with is that although I specify `numToI` is a `HashMap<i32, usize>`, not `HashMap<&i32, usize>`, and I dereference to get the value of `v` with `*v` and assign the value to `num`, when I check if the `HashMap` `numToI` contains this `i32` dereferenced value as a key, I get the error: expected `&i32`, found `i32` on the call to `contains_key`. Why is this? Is it because the HashMap type always requires a pointer rather than a raw value, or is it due to an intricacy of Rust I'm not aware of? Shouldn't it expect a pointer for the key instead of a `i32` if I had used `HashMap<&i32, i32>`?

More importantly, if this is due to a difference between Rust and C that has to do with the way borrowing etc. is used in Rust, where can I learn more about the intricacies of these differences?

Comment: Lookup the documentation for contains_key(), it expects a pointer. Also you may want to use into_iter() rather than just iter() as the former will give you a copy of the value instead of a pointer to the value

Comment: Have a look at the [`contains_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.contains_key) example. Side note: even if `contains_key` takes a reference, the hashing and comparison is always done on the value, not the reference. Oh, and: The rust compiler is telling you to do the right thing in its error output: `help: consider borrowing here: &complement`. Read it.

Comment: By the way, can I rant a bit about leetcode? If they do unidiomatic things like asking this function returning a `Vec<i32>` and ask to encode "not found" as `[-1, -1]` instead of returning an `Option<(usize, usize)>`, they're a really terrible resource to learn about Rust.

Comment: Nit: it's better to use `if let Some(v) = map.get_key()` than `contains_key()` then `get()`.

Comment: @Caesar I hate them since they use `Rc<RefCell<T>>` for trees, instead of simple `Box`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`contains_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.contains_key) takes a reference. It doesn't need to take ownership of the value to test with - it just needs to look at it temporarily.

Rust is complaining that you are passing in an `i32` by value instead of a reference to it. It should tell you to borrow instead: `numToI.contains_key(&complement)`.

That's the only issue with your code, really. `HashMap` keys don't need to be references, and it would be really inconvenient if they did.